# Routing in microservices - stuck with basics

Tags: scala, spray, akka-http

I am building a simple RESTful microservice using akka-http that stores data in cassandra. I have cassandra part working and most of the service part except can't figure out the routing part. I understand the concept but stuck in the specifics. Here's the code for my service which I can't get to compile.

```
val routes = {

  pathPrefix("users") {

    get {
      // GET /users
      path(Rest) {
        // Push handling to another context to avoid blocking
        complete {
          val f: Future[List[Users]] = service.getAllUsers()

          f onComplete  {
            case Success(list: List[Users]) => {
              list.toJson()
            }
          f onFailure() => {

            }
          }
        }
      }
    } ~
      // GET /users/{email}
    path(Rest) { email: String =>
      val found: Future[Option[Users]] = service.getByUsersEmail(email)

      complete {
        found onComplete {
          case Success(user: Users) => {
            user.toJson()
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

UsersService is a data service for cassandra with all methods returning futures. I do want all responses to be JSON which I think can be handled with spray (  implicit val jsonFormatUsers = jsonFormat5(Users) or custom PersonJsonProtocol which I have) but not sure exactly how to use it from within the routes code.

Thanks in advance, I know this is fairly simple to many of you guys :)

Comment: Type mismatch, expected: ToResponseMarshallable, actual Unit; however I'm sure the code block is incomplete. What do I need to do convert the response into JSON and complete request successfully - as I'm not sure if list.toJason() will work.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't return list of of users in your complete directive, but retun Unit. Future's method onComplete returns Unit. You said that you had json formatters defined in scope and I guess you've mixed in SprayJsonProtocol and also you have implcit execution context in scope. If yes then you can just write

```
complete {
    service.getAllUsers()
}
```

And all the magic will be done.

Comment: Wish the magic was done, but not yet :( I have   implicit val jsonFormatUsers = jsonFormat5(Users) in scope, is that going to do it? I also have a PersonJsonProtocol class but not sure how it is used. Also, what goes in the future's onComplete to return the result and what type should it be? Sorry for the newbie questions.

Comment: trait Service extends CassandraSpec with UsersService {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem

  implicit def executor: ExecutionContextExecutor
  implicit val jsonFormatUsers = jsonFormat5(Users)

  val routes = {

      pathPrefix("users") {
        get {
          path(Rest) {
            complete {
              val f: Future[List[Users]] = service.getAllUsers()
              f onComplete  {
                case Success(list: List[Users]) => {
                  list.toJson()
                }
              f onFailure() => {
                }
              }
            }

Comment: I do have object PersonJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {} with read and write method, and its in scope for the Service class. But I'm not sure how its applied to the list of Users - would it happen implicitly or I need to provide marshalling/unmarshalling for the List[Users] as well.

Comment: your method doesn't return future List, but future Unit. You should return Future[List[User]] in complete directive.

Comment: My methods do return Future[List[Users]] and Future[Option[Users]] so that should not be an issue. I still think its not picking up the json marshalling code because all spray and custom json imports are grayed out in Intellij means they are not being used. `    def getAllUsers(): Future[List[Users]] = {
      usersModel.model.select.where(_ => usersModel.model.email eqs "*").fetch()
    }

    def getByUsersEmail(email: String): Future[Option[Users]] = {
      usersModel.model.select.where(_ => usersModel.model.email eqs email).one()
    }`

Comment: but you wrote this: val f: Future[List[Users]] = service.getAllUsers() f onComplete { case Success(list: List[Users]) => { list.toJson() } f onFailure() => { } }
This code doesn't return  Future[List[Users]]

Comment: I have changed it to the following but with no luck : pathPrefix("users") {
        (get & path(Segment)) { email =>
          complete (
            service.getByUsersEmail(email)
          )
        }
        get {
          // GET /users
          path(Rest) {
            complete (
              service.getAllUsers()
            )
          }
        } ~

Comment: can you edit your answer? what did you change and what did you get after the change and also what you have in scope(I mean what implcits are in scope)